# Why data is not output from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

When the page is loaded, I take the data from the input from the ID of my page and transmit it using ajax to show_comment.php

```
 <?php 
require_once('vender/show_comment.php');
?>//I'm connecting a file to display comments

<input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="1">
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let page_id = $('input[name="page_id"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'vender/show_comment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            page_id: page_id
        }
    });
});
```

After that, I access the table in the database where my comments are stored and select all the rows where page_id is equal to my page number. Next, I check whether such records exist.If there are, then I will transform my entire result into associative arrays.And I do further monepulations, but as a result, nothing happens in the final file.

```
//show_comment.php
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

$page_id=$_POST['page_id'];

$query="SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_id`= ?";
$stmt=$link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$page_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    $comments=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($comments as $comment){
    $user_id=$comment['user_id'];
    $query_user="SELECT * FROM `users_login` WHERE `id`=?";
    $stmt_user=$link->prepare($query_user);
    $stmt_user->bind_param("s",$user_id);
    $stmt_user->execute();
    $result_user=$stmt_user->get_result(); 
    $user_info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_user);
?>
<div class="new-comment">
    <img src="<?php echo $user_info['avatar']?>">
    <p><?php echo $user_info['name']?></p>
    <p><?php echo $comment['message']?></p>
</div>

<?php
    }
}
?>
```

The database is connected accurately without errors and all the tables from it are also connected and they are filled

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI9Do.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxCA1.png)

I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: This question must be closed because lacking debugging details. But I closed it as a duplicate, that points to answer which can help you to get the debugging details. You should really watch the data flow from the browser to PHP and back. THIS is what you must provide in your question instead of those database pictures: what your js sent to PHP backend and what your PHP sent back.